# how to do Zero pading in CUDA for covolution

Tags: cuda, padding, zero, convolution

hi i have to convolve two signals[ pulseMatrixRow[i] and pulse[i] ] using CUFFT. for that my code is 
    int main(int argc, char **argv)

```
{
FILE *fileWritePtr;
cufftComplex h_signal[NX*BATCH];
cufftComplex h_filter_signal[NX*BATCH];
cufftComplex hf_signal[NX*BATCH];   

// Initalize the memory for the signal
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIGNAL_SIZE; ++i)
{
    h_signal[i].x = pulseMatrixRow[i];
    h_signal[i].y = pulseMatrixRow[i];
}

// device memory allocation 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_signal, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH);

// transfer to device memory
cudaMemcpy(d_signal, h_signal, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



// Initalize the memory for the filter
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < FILTER_signal_SIZE; ++i)

{
    h_filter_signal[i].x = pulse[i];
    h_filter_signal[i].y = pulse[i];
}


// device memory allocation 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_filter_signal, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH);

// transfer to device memory
   cudaMemcpy(d_filter_signal, h_filter_signal, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH,         cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // CUFFT plan

  cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);

  // Transform signal and fsignal

 printf("Transforming signal cufftExecC2C\n");
  cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, (cufftComplex *)d_signal,     CUFFT_FORWARD);


printf("Transforming filter_signal cufftExecC2C\n");
cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_filter_signal, (cufftComplex     *)d_filter_signal, CUFFT_FORWARD);



// Multiply the coefficients together 
ComplexPointwiseMulAndScale<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_signal, d_filter_signal, NX, 1.0f/NX*BATCH);


// Transform signal back
printf("Transforming signal back cufftExecC2C\n");
cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, CUFFT_INVERSE);



// transfer results from GPU memory 


cudaMemcpy(hf_signal, d_signal, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


fileWritePtr = fopen("OutputData1.txt","w+");

for(i = 0; i < NX ; i++){
    //printf("%f %f\n", i, hf_signal[i].x, hf_signal[i].y);
     fprintf(fileWritePtr,"%d %f %f\n", i, hf_signal[i].x, hf_signal[i].y);
     }
fclose(fileWritePtr);



//Destroy CUFFT context
cufftDestroy(plan);

 // cleanup memory
 cudaFree(d_signal);
 cudaFree(d_filter_signal);


 // free(h_signal);
 // free(h_filter_signal);

return 0;

 }
```

my pulseMatrix code generated by matlab is given as:

```
pulse = [ones(1,50) zeros(1,500-50)];
pulseMatrix = repmat(pulse,10,1);
pulseMatrix = pulseMatrix.';
pulseMatrixRow = pulseMatrix(:);
```

but i have to process only 1000 samples of pulseMatrixRow at a single time and rest as set of 1000 one by one. 
As my fft is 1024.,please tell how and at which stage i have to pad the zeros at the end of my input signal and for my filter signal which is simply given as
    pulse = [ones(1,50) zeros(1,500-50)];

Comment: It seems a question of signal processing/FFT/DFT theory, rather than a question of programming/CUDA library. I think you can set the trailing 24 elements of `d_signal` and the trailing 524 elements of `d_filter_signal` to zero before doing fft.

Comment: yes sir, but i am new to programming, please tell how to set the elements to zero and at what stage.......

Answer (score 1):

You could use `memset()` to zero the padding of the host mem, before transfering it to device mem, or

you could use `cudaMemset()` to zero the padding of the device mem, before doing fft and after the host to device memory transfer.

Please refer to [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) for how to use `memset()`.

Please refer to [this link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee) for how to use `cudaMemset()`.

Comment: sir,basically i tried to use this command but as per my knowledge, it use to set the certain defined values to zero, like if i am passing 100 samples,it is used to set the values from that 100 only to zero. but if i have to pass 100 values and then pad 24 zeros at the end of it, what to do?

Comment: @Ankit you could calculate the starting addr of the 24 elments and then pass it to `memset()` like this `memset(&array[1000], 0, 24*sizeof(array[0]));`

Comment: sir, by using this command my first thousand values are becoming zero and next 24 are all 1s.

Comment: @Ankit Sorry I can't tell what's wrong without more information. You could post your complete code to allow others see if you are using `memset()` in a right way.